# Accessing "final" fields of a superclass in a subclass (and updating them) in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, final

I have a field for Buildings and subclasses of different types of Buildings that inherit from the `Buildings` class. The `Buildings` class has a field called "`totalNumber`" which I want to update every time I add a building in one of my subclasses.

I want `totalNumber` in Buildings class to always show the total number of buildings that have been made.

Shall I use the "final" keyword for the "`totalNumber`" field in this case?

What happens if inside an object of the subclass "`Cottage`" i.e. `cott` I call

`cott.totalNumber = cott.totalNumber += 1`?

Will it update the field it inherited?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Final fields cannot be mutated once initialized, so you would not want to use them to count the total number of buildings made. I would also consider some kind of state manager that keeps track of buildings.

Comment: However, if the final field is a reference to a mutable object, then that object can be updated even if the instance field that refers to it can not.  You could use `AtomicInteger`, for example to contain your count.

Answer (score 3):

`final` means you can once assign a value when initializing the variable, and afterwards it's readonly. what you're looking for would be in the simplest case some sort of `static` variable that counts created instances of `Buildings`. But this could be easily done this way:

```
public class Buildings{
     //a simple counter for created instances
     private static int createdInstances = 0;

     public Buildings(){
          //new instance created -> increment counter
          createdInstances++;
     }
}
```

If you create an instance of a subclass, the constructor of the superclass is always called aswell, so you don't need to do anything in the subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you expressed a desire to count instances of subclasses that you create. This really isn't in the responsibilities that any of those classes would have. With your requirement, I would implement a solution something like this:

```
abstract class Building { }

final class Cottage extends Building { }

final class House extends Building { }

final class Castle extends Building { }

final class BuildingManager {
    private final static BuildingManager _instance = new BuildingManager();
    private Set<Building> buildings;

    private BuildingManager() {
        buildings = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public static BuildingManager getManager() {
        return _instance;
    }

    public Building getNewBuilding() {
        // decide which building to create, but we'll always go with
        // a castle for this example

        Building castle = new Castle();
        buildings.add(castle);
        return castle;
    }

    public int getBuildingCount() {
        return buildings.size();
    }
}
```

`BuildingManager` is solely responsible for managing creation and counting of `Building`'s.

With that in place, you would use it like this:

```
BuildingManager manager = BuildingManager.getManager();

Building building = manager.getNewBuilding();
Building building2 = manager.getNewBuilding();

System.out.println(manager.getBuildingCount() + " buildings exist.");
```

which will output:

```
2 buildings exist.
```

---

To answer your specific questions:

> I want totalNumber in Buildings class to always show the total number of buildings that have been made. Would I use the "final" keyword for the "totalNumber" field in this case?

No. A final value field couldn't be changed once initialized. You could use object to store this (kudos to @scottb to mentioning [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html)), but that doesn't change the fact that counting how many buildings exist in your application's state is [outside of the responsibilities](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SeparationOfConcerns) that `Building` would have.

> What happens if inside an object of the subclass "Cottage", cott I call cott.totalNumber = cott.totalNumber += 1? Will it update the field it inherited?

No. It would be a fair assumption that if `Building` kept a counter, it would be a static field or method, and thus be something like

```
Building.incrementCount();
```

An inherited field from a superclass is still unique to that specific instance.